# How do I stop this from being greedy

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following regex:

```
#^/workorder/(.*)/#
```

Provided the following URI's:

```
/workorder/archive/2/
```

The $matches variable from preg_match() is returning `archive/2/`

Why doesn't the last `/` in the regex stop the `(.*)` from being greedy? What do I add to make the regex stop when the `/` delimiter is found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it.

```
^/workorder/([^/]*)/
```

Comment: Seems to work...thank you greatly was going nutts trying to figure this out :)

Comment: Please check the answer from bsdnoobz. It's good to know about the non-greedy switch, but realize the performance hit it requires.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `(.*)` with `(.*?)` to make it non-greedy.

Here's a good explanation: [Greedy and Non-Greedy Matches](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch06_16.htm)

Answer (score 2):

To make it not greedy (lazy) use

```
^/workorder/(.*?)/
```

But this will use backtracking which is not good for performance. Use

```
^/workorder/([^/]*)/
```

To have your cake and eat it fast